# How do I change default search provider in Firefox?

Tags: samsung, firefox-for-android

I have been using All the Internet on my computer and now I want to make it my main search provider in Firefox on my Galaxy S20.

Does anyone know how to change your main search provider so it would now be alltheinternet.com ?  I would love to be able to have it on both my computer and on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually add a search provider to Firefox this way:

1. Open Firefox app
2. Click on the 3-dots-menu (in the new Firefox version in the lower right corner:

[image]

3. Select `Settings`
4. Select `Search`
5. Select `Add search engine`
6. Select the option `Other` and enter the following values:

- Name: `All the Internet` (adapt to your preferences)
- Search string: `https://www.alltheinternet.com/?q=%s`

[image]

7. Save the entered values using the check mark in the top right corner
8. Mark the entry "All the Internet" in he search engine list as default search engine.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure a different/custom search engine as follows:

1. Open Firefox
2. Click on the 3-dots-symbol (top right corner)
3. Click "Settings"
4. Click "Search"
5. Select another search engine as standard (by just clicking on it) or add a custom one (which is the last possible action in the list of available options)

Comment: the 3-dots icon is now on the lower right corner (new Firefox version). And the list of available search engines does not contain an entry for alltheinternet.com".

Comment: Well, it depends on your settings. Actually, you can lift the url/settings bar up again (as it used to be). It's just the default setting that has changed, indeed. And yes, alltheinternet.com is not part of the readily available options. But that's why I stated that one may add custom search engine.